# Disregard certain lines if false

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote this query and it is designed to send an email to a customer with info in a database. I would like it to do a check for any values that return as 0 and not send them in the @message. I imagine I'll need an if statement but I haven't been able to figure out how to make it work. Any help is appreciated.

Query:

```
select @AssignedCount = (select COUNT(*)
 FROM event
 where status_name = 'ASSIGNED' AND primary_unitid = NULL
 OR status_name = 'ASSIGNED' AND primary_unitid = '')

select @UnitResource = (select COUNT (*)
from unit_resources
where unit_seqnum NOT IN (select unit_seqnum from unit))

select @UnitEmployee = (select COUNT (*)
from unit_employees
where unit_seqnum NOT IN (select unit_seqnum from unit))

select @LoggedOff = (select COUNT(*) 
from unit 
where status_name = 'LOGGED_OFF')

select @Duplicates = (SELECT ISNULL(
(select COUNT(*)
from unit
group by unitid 
having COUNT(*) > 1), 0))


select @message =


'Status Report' +
'   Events in assigned status with no primary unit: '
+ REPLACE((str(@AssignedCount)),' ','') +

' Un-linked unit resource table rows: '
+ REPLACE((str(@UnitResource)),' ','') +

' Un-linked Unit resource table rows: '
+ REPLACE((str(@UnitEmployee)),' ','') + 

'   Units with a status of Logged Off: '
+ REPLACE((str(@LoggedOff)),' ','') +

'   Duplicate Units: '
+ REPLACE((str(@Duplicates)),' ','')`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use if statements to dynamically build the string:

```
-- setting to blank; otherwise, the string would be null
set @message = ''

-- dynamically building @message with if statements
if @AssignedCount > 0
    set @message =  'Status Report' +
                    '   Events in assigned status with no primary unit: '
                    + REPLACE((str(@AssignedCount)),' ','')

if @UnitResource > 0
    set @message = @message + ' Un-linked unit resource table rows: '
                            + REPLACE((str(@UnitResource)),' ','')

if @UnitEmployee > 0
    set @message = @message + ' Un-linked Unit resource table rows: '
                            + REPLACE((str(@UnitEmployee)),' ','')

if @LoggedOff > 0
    set @message = @message + '   Units with a status of Logged Off: '
                            + REPLACE((str(@LoggedOff)),' ','')

if @Duplicates > 0
    set @message = @message + '   Duplicate Units: '
                            + REPLACE((str(@Duplicates)),' ','')

-- removing leading space from @message if AssignedCount is 0
set @message = ltrim(@message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, actually, rather than a bunch of `IF` statements, I'd likely go for something like this and do it all in one go:

```
SET @message = CONCAT('Status Report',
                      (SELECT CONCAT('   Events in assigned status with no primary unit: ',COUNT(*))
                       FROM event
                       WHERE status_name = 'ASSIGNED'
                         AND primary_unitid = NULL
                          OR status_name = 'ASSIGNED'
                         AND primary_unitid = ''
                       HAVING COUNT(*) > 0),
                      ((SELECT CONCAT(' Un-linked unit resource table rows: ',COUNT (*))
                        FROM unit_resources ur
                        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 --I changed this from a NOT IN to an EXISTS, as NOT in have behave oddly with NULLs
                                          FROM unit u
                                          WHERE u.unit_seqnum = ur.seqnum)
                        HAVING COUNT(*) > 0))); --You get the idea now
```

I haven't done the whole lot here, however, the `HAVING COUNT(*) > 0` means that no rows (including `0`) will be returned when there are no relevant rows. This means that information won't be concatenated to the value of `@message`.

Comment: The only issue with this is that I need the variables that are set for other portions of the query. So doing it all in one go causes other complications.

Example: If no errors are found, the email should not be sent at all. So for the insert, I have a variable called "ErrorCount" and it counts the values stored for each variable set.